# How do I turn an int into a float?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
int *SliderMaximum = V1.TeamAmountAfterSave;
[sliderTeamSelect setmaximum:SliderMaximum];
```

I need to convert `SliderMaximum` to a float how do I do this?

Comment: Is it an `int` or a pointer to an `int`? You can convert `int` into a `float` by a simple assignment.

Comment: It's important around here to put your best foot forward when you ask a question. Make sure to clearly state your problem, what you've tried, and provide as many details as you think might be helpful. Also, if it's something that even a minute or two searching the web will give you a satisfactory answer, then it's probably not a good fit for a question. But please stick around to learn more, I know you are just getting started. Just please don't forget there are other resources more appropriate for some questions than others.

Comment: Also - what @Sulthan said. Does the `TeamAmountAfterSave` property (which should not start with a capital letter BTW, please read and follow Objective-C naming conventions, they are quite important for some language features!) return an `int` or an `int*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSNumber *yourNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: SliderMaximum];
float yourFloat = [yourNumber floatValue];
```

and you don't need a *pointer to int*, it's useless, computationally allocate a *pointer* and write inside *address pointer to int* is same as allocate a *int* and write *int* in it.

Comment: This worked perfectly ty verry much.

Comment: If it solves your problem it's a good manner to accept the answer (a tick mark near the answer) and up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried multiplying it by a float?

CGFloat sliderMaximum = SliderMaximum * 1.0f;

Comment: Yeah this gives an error: Initializing CGFloat * (aka float)...

Comment: That's because you have SliderMaximum as an `int *` when it should just be an `int`. You rarely need to pass primitives about by reference.

Comment: I changed the pointer.
This makes it say that it expects an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
[sliderTeamSelect setmaximum:[[V1.TeamAmountAfterSave] floatValue]];
```

Comment: This makes it say that it expects an identifier.